# How to set a field as a date in a Community Connector?

Tags: javascript, looker-studio

On the reference page of Google Studio Community Connectors they give this example

```
{
  "name": "Created",
  "label": "Date Created",
  "dataType": "STRING",
  "semantics": {
    "conceptType": "DIMENSION"
  }
}
```

but using that example I end up with an actual string type in Google Data Studio and I am unable to use the field in any date related charts.

Answer (score 1):

Update (2017-12-14): The new schema customization feature will let you [manually set semantic types](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics#manual-semantic-types). View the reference for [getSchema](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getschema)
 and [SemanticType](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#semantictype) for full details. This should resolve the issue.

---

Data types (number, string, boolean) and semantic types (date, geo etc) are handled differently in Data Studio as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics). To use date in your charts:

- Ensure your date field is in one of the Date formats as explained in the [guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics#date_time).
- Schema should mention `string` as the `dataType` for your date field.
- For `getData()` calls when `sampleExtraction` is set to `true`, use one of the [options to handle semantic detection](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics#options_for_handling_semantic_type_detection). If you are passing multiple rows/records, ensure that none of them is null for the date field.

This should automatically detect your field as date in the fields selection screen.

Comment: can you provide sample code?

Answer (score 0):

For me working with dates became a horror

After I've created a first deploy, it showed nulls instead of dates. New deployed versions did not fix the issue, even when the code was fixed.

I had to kill my deployment, and start a new one.

Here's a sample code for date:

`Schema`

```
    const created = fields.newDimension()
        .setId('created')
        .setName('created')
        .setName('Created')
        .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY_SECOND)
```

`Data`

```
/**
 * @param {Object} responseRow - key-value pair got from API
 * @param {DataStudioApp.Fields} requestedFields
 * 
 * @returns {ConnectorGetDataRow}
 */
function getFormattedDataRow_(responseRow, requestedFields) {
    const types = cc.FieldType;

    if (responseRow === undefined) {
        throw 'responseRow is undefined';
    }
    
    let row = [];
    let value = null;
    requestedFields.asArray().map((field) => {
        value = responseRow[field.getId()];
        if (value === null) {
            value = '';
        }
        if (field.getType() === types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY_SECOND) {
            value = formatDateToString_(new Date(value));
        }
        row.push(value);
    });
    return {
        values: row
    }
}
```

`helper`

```
/**
 * @param {Date} date
 * 
 * @returns {String}
 */
function formatDateToString_(date) {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const minutes = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const seconds = date.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');

  return `${year}${month}${day}${hours}${minutes}${seconds}`;
}
```